# Include a big generated file in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm testing Webpack capabilities and have a funny use case that I don't know how to handle. Namely, I've got:

1. File `A.js`: a JS module that uses Webpack imports and defines a lot of variables and utility functions.
2. File `B.js`: a big (>10mb) JS file generated from another programming language, which is supposed to use variables and functions defined in `A.js`, however, it is not a Webpack module and does not use Webpack imports.

Now I want to use both them in a single environment, but:

1. I don't want to compile them into a single file (it takes too long and it's obviously unnecessary). I would love to have generated bundle from A.js (and other local JS files, that A uses) and want to just use B.js without unnecessary transformations.
2. I do not want Webpack to even parse B.js looking for imports etc to minimize the build time. I just want to tell Webpack that B.js should be able to access the scope of A.js.

Is it possible? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have any additional build tool along side webpack, i would suggest to let that build/assembly tool handle `B.js` and keep it outside webpack bundling. This way webpack doesnt even know there is `B.js`. It also means no processing on that big `B.js` by webpack.

If thats not the case (i.e. only webpack is in place) then i would suggest to use [`script-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/). However, this would mean webpack will make a bundle of that entire `B.js`. Expect things to be slow here with webpack.

On my mac, webpack takes 2+ seconds for a 17 MB js file with [`script-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/). Without the big js file it takes 100 ms.